# Greek questionmark (semicolon), has any special meaning in this code?

Tags: php

I am maintaining the code from another developer, and I just found this code in the source code if his files:

```
function update($set, $args)
{
;
    if(!empty($args))
    {
        if(!empty($args['id']))
        {
            $id = $args['id'];
            return update_post_meta($id, '_quizdata', $set);
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

As you can see, in `line three` there is a greek questionmark. This question mark can have any special meaning or can harm the code somehow ?

Is the first time I see something like that. Also, I do not get any error in my error logs, but I don't even know, if this code is executed in order to produce any error.

Kind regards

Comment: Did you mean the `;` semicolon? That's redundant there, terminates an empty statement.

Comment: Yes this is what I mean. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing, is a simple empty statement

Comment: Nop, you can delete this without problems.

Comment: Kind regards ! :) I will mark your answer as correct in a few minutes